# Python exec() to assign variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `exec()` with Python 3 and PyQt5. I am making my first ever GUI and teaching myself as I go.

I have button names assigned as "space##" in a for loop, and later I need to call the button name to get the text value or label. If I use this:

```
someVar = self.space33.text()
print(someVar)
```

it returns:

"Text in the button 'space33'"

But if I try this:

```
command = ("someVar = self.space33.text()")
exec(command)
print(someVar)
```

I get an error saying that someVar is not defined.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to tell for sure, but if you assign to `somevar` anywhere else in the function that contains that `exec()`, it's a local variable in that function. You can't modify locals using `exec()`.

Comment: Please provide more relevant code for context because with what you've given I don't think it's possible to get that error.

Comment: I have it assigned in a PyQt function that is called when a button is pushed.  I have tried initializing the variable inside and outside the function, the print command is use the very next line, and the variable is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Don't use `exec`. Use a real data structure, like a list or a dict.

Comment: I don think I can use a list because I am assigning button names in PyQt. They are their own entity.

Comment: No, if you can put something in a variable, you can put it in a list.